# MS Word index not working for short words

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, formatting, office365, microsoft-word-365

In MS Word 365, when I bookmark words in the text to be shown in the final index, then it seems that those words can be too sall..

In this screenshot you can see the issue in the generated index with the short word `ur`:

[image]

I have checked the box to have the page numbers justified right with leading dots. But this does not work on too short words that are below two-three letters/characters. For those, the setting for justifying right with leading dots is ignored and the page number is shown right next to the word, cramped close to it, as shown.

Below is the settings window where I have checked the "Justify right... (Højrejuster...)" checkbox and chosen the leading dots.

Any method to make this work for words of any length?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a simple paragraph formatting issue - the hanging indent is too large which confuses the choice to push the numbers across to the right.

You can modify the built-in style "Index 1", or just select the whole index and modify the paragraph format, and adjust the hanging indent to something smaller eg 0.2 cm rather than 0.39 which seems to be the default (=0.1 inches)